# How to record audio from HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm writing a chrome extension for a site that offers IP-telephony. When the call starts, the site creates an `<audio>` tag and sets its `srcObject`. I'm using console first to make a POC of how I could capture it. Here's what I've got:

```
let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(document.querySelector('#phone').srcObject);
let chunks = [];

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  console.log(Date.now(), 'ondata', e);
  chunks.push(e.data);

  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    let base64data = reader.result;
    console.log(base64data);  // Logs the base64 data
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(e.data);
}

mediaRecorder.onerror = function(event) {
  console.error("MediaRecorder error: ", event);
};

mediaRecorder.start(1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
}, 5000);
```

I run it from console when the audio is playing and it prints 5 chunks that start with `data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,QMqB...`. I expect these to contain 1 second long parts of the audio. However I can not replay any of them. I do `new Audio('data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,QMqB...').play()` and all I get is `DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.`. The error is the same when I try to JSFiddle with button onlick. Am I missing something?